# When does a component unmount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My current understanding is that a component mounts onto the DOM when it is needed to be seen or when the route requires that component. It will also render its child components. Does this mean that a component will be unmounted when you visit a route that doesn't have that component or whenever you visit any page that doesn't show the element that component produces? Thus, a component will need to be remounted every time it shows up on the DOM (outside of prop and state changes), correct?

Answer (score 42):

During the **VirtualDOM Reconciliation** if a component existed but no longer will, the component is considered unmounted and given a chance to clean up (via `componentWillUnmount`).

The reverse is true, during the reconciliation, if a component didn't exist, but now does, the component is considered ready to mount, and given a chance to prep itself (`constructor` / `componentWillMount`)

> When tearing down a tree, old DOM nodes are destroyed. Component
>   instances receive componentWillUnmount(). When building up a new tree,
>   new DOM nodes are inserted into the DOM. Component instances receive
>   componentWillMount() and then componentDidMount(). Any state
>   associated with the old tree is lost.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html

That particular page is well worth a read if you haven't already. It also explains why `key` is pretty important for repeated elements.

Comment: I've been searching for this link/concept for quite some time, but couldn't for the love of god formulate the google query. thank you.

Comment: I know right? For some reason I always find it hard to locate stuff on the docs. Not their fault, I just put it down to new terms and concepts not present in other JS frameworks

Comment: I probably need to adjust this answer slightly to take into account hooks, but I think the overall message is the same..

Comment: @Chris And what would that adjustment be wrt. hooks? :)

Comment: @GlennMohammad Well, the message is basically the same - it unmounts when it was present but is no longer present. The approach to reconciliation is the same. What differs is what is called when it unmounts, and for hooks this is any functions returned by a useEffect hook present in the component that has unmounted.

Comment: this simply shifts the question to: ok so what is it that causes the "tearing down of a tree"? or what causes virtual DOM reconciliation

Comment: @KarimKamel I would argue that is a different question rather than "shifting" the question.

Answer (score 15):

Component will be mounted on DOM only when it needs to be rendered. If you change the route or refresh the page or you want to render your component on specific events (eg onClick show/hide the component) then componentWillUnmount()  will be called and component will be removed from DOM

Comment: I am having an issue unmounting a child component from the parent component. please help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56874753/why-is-unmounting-a-child-component-displays-an-error

Comment: sublime :-))))))

Answer (score 8):

Simply put, when a component has mounted, `componentDidMount()` is called, when the component is about to unmount, `componentWillUnmount()` is called. During re-rendering, if the component is neither to be mounted nor unmounted, neither of the aforementioned methods will be called. Instead, simply the changes made to the code of the component will be updated.

Please remember that most React apps are Single Page Apps which means they only update the existing page, they don't create any new page like page1.html, page2.html. What happens is that React unmounts unnecessary components from page1 and mounts necessary components described in page2 such that it looks like page2. But it doesn't really "leave page1.html" and take you to a whole new page called page2.html. All it does is simply pop and push components in one canvas or page. In other words, React "brings" page2 into page1. But the canvas remains the same(page1).

So, the answer to your question is, yes, a component will unmount and remount when its removed or added to the page.

Answer (score 1):

I would say a component mount onto the DOM only if it's used via another component, including a Router component. Don't think of routers as special elements/things in React. They're like other components and they do a matching between current URL and the patterns they have to decide which component should be rendered via the `render()` function of Router. Whenever there is a change of URL, the router picks the new component to render and does rendering via `render()` function.

Comment: I meant router has it's own `render()` function and uses related component there based on what patterns match current URL. something like this implementation https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/modules/Router.js#L126