# React component mounting/unmounting with regard to if else statement in render

Tags: reactjs

When exactly is a child component constructed vs rerenderes? I googled that the key property might have something to do, but I can't figure it out. Also, say in the parent render function I have if true return A, else return B. What happen in this situation?

Comment: Keys are just there when you have sibling elements of the same type (component), so React can easily differentiate between them and know which un to update (rerender). 

Concerning when is a component constructed - components are mounted at the point of their initial render, and unmounted when it completely disappears. Note that if you have, for instance, paging of a list of components, they might just get reused (updated), although the key has changed)

For a better understanding of the React lifecycle, just write your scenarios and console.log when lifecycle methods are called.

Comment: So how does react even know which child to update? If reusing could happen as u mention, how does react know there won't be hidden logic such as form default value that can't be reused.

Comment: The example I've mentioned is something I've come across in development and I'm not completely sure when does it apply. But, in general, if the DOM didn't change, React will not call unmount a component and will just call update to update its props. In a scenario like that React will not apply any logic that is connected with the mounting lifecycle methods, just the update ones.

Comment: A better explanation about unmounting can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41499312/7821979

Answer (score 2):

If A and B are different components, React will unmount one and mount the other if something has changed.

But, if they are the same, the reconciliation algorithm might just change any refs, change the props and call update. I agree that the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) are not clear enough there and I'm unsure if and when have any changes been made from version to version.

However, if this is the case (A and B are from the same component) you should not be writing your code like that but rather something like this:

```
<Component { condition ? ...propsA : ...propsB } />
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for sharing.  Super helpful info that I was not aware of.