# useEffect run once for every component instance

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have been using `useEffect()` with `[]` as an argument for code that I wanted to run once. But after already building many projects I found out that if it runs once when one instance of the component somewhere renders, It wouldn't run anywhere else at all. This means if you reuse that component elsewhere, it won't run in them even if they are rendering for the first time.

Parent Component

```
  const [bl, setBl] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={(e) => setBl(!bl)}>Click</button>
      {bl ? <Comp page="page1" /> : <Comp page="page2" />}
    </div>
  );
```

Child Component

```
function Comp({ page }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(page);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Component at {page}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here it only logs "page1" and doesn't log anything for the other component, ie page2

In order to log the pagename once in every instance, I am now adding the line `var rnd = Math.random();` before use effect, and adding `[rnd]` as a parameter, so that it runs once in every instance.

So my question is, is there a better way of doing this? meaning running once in every instance, better than depending on random chance like I am using?

I can use `[page]` here, but what about if there is no any unique prop like here?

You can check the codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-forest-wrkdd)

Comment: Your opening paragraph seems to contradict itself, if it runs once per instance, then surely it **will** run in each one? Have you tried including multiple instances without a conditional?

Comment: @DBS language ambiguity, I edited that thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React component mounting/unmounting with regard to if else statement in render](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48245455/6367213)

Comment: You could achieve the same effect with a single component: `<Comp {...(bl ? {page:"page1"} : {page:"page2"})} />`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that, for React, replacing `<Comp page="page1" />` with `<Comp page="page2" />` can't be distinguished from simply updating prop value in existing component.

As a consequence, when `bl` changes, React won't unmount the old `Comp` and mount another one - it will simply update existing component, and rerender will trigger effects only is their dependencies have changed. In you case, dependency list is empty, so the effect is run only once - on mount.

To achieve what you want, you can try to force the remount on state change, i.e. make React see that two instances of `Comp` are independent ones. For this, you can use the special `key` prop - it is usually used for element lists, but here can be used too:

```
  const [bl, setBl] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={(e) => setBl(!bl)}>Click</button>
      {bl ? <Comp key="page1" page="page1" /> : <Comp key="page2" page="page2" />}
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

> I found out that if it runs once when one instance of the component somewhere renders, It wouldn't run anywhere else at all

Not at all :)

`UseEffect` triggers for each Components mount. But not for an update if you have your dependency array empty!

And that your case here, React only update `page` props on the same component, so it do not trigger your `useEffect`.

You have 2 solutions:

- Either add your `page` prop to your `useEffect` dependency array (so each time `page` change, your `useEffect` will be triggered)
- Add a `key` to your component, which is different depending on your if/else. For React, if it's "the same" component, but with a different key across 2 renders, React will unmount the first one, and mount the second (so your `useEffect` will be trigered)

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the dependent variable in the dependencies list for useEffect:

```
function Comp({ page }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(page);
  }, [page]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Component at {page}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I would do that. but what if the component doesn't have any unique prop