# Stale State in useEffect and setInterval

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, google-cloud-functions

So I am working on an app, which as a main functionality uses a timer.
However as the timer should not be user manipulated it shall run on the backend, this is being achieved with firebase cloud functions and server timestamps.

Currently I am using an useEffect Hook on the Page which intializes the Timer with setInterval and an empty dependency Array so that the timer gets only Started once on Component mount. In the setInterval Callback there is a function called "getPoolTime", this async function calls a cloudFunction that writes a new serverTimestamp to firestore and calculates the remaining time, based on other factors. (Probably not the most efficient way to do this, but it was the only way I could figure out for now xD ).

The problem I have now is, even if the timer ran out, setInterval still calls "getPoolTime" which invokes a cloud function and this is not very efficient. I want the cloud function not being invoked when the timer ran out.

I tried:

1. if Statement in the useEffect Hook, so when the timer state is say < 1 do not call "getPoolTime" anymore, however as the the timer only mounts at component mount, there is the problem of stale state and therefore this does not work.
2. If Statement in the "getPoolTime" function, which leads to the problem that once the timer has reached zero it can never be restarted as even if the function is invoked the state is < 1 doesn't pass the if check and the new time is never calculated.

So I guess the solution I need is, something that starts the timer and calls the "getPoolTime" on mount until timerDisplay < 1 and on mount calls "getPoolTime" once again.

Thank you for your help - I am well aware that what I am doing is probably really inefficient and there are certainly better ways to do it - if you look at my code and have an idea how I could make it better, let me know - I am eager to learn!

```
const [timerDisplay, setTimerDisplay] = useState(0);

  async function getPoolTime() {
    try {
      const setWriteTimestamp = httpsCallable(functions, "setWriteTimestamp");
      setWriteTimestamp({ slug: slug });
      const poolRef = doc(db, "pools", slug);
      const poolSnap = await getDoc(poolRef);
      const timeLeft =
        poolSnap.data().expTimestamp.toMillis() / 1000 -
        poolSnap.data().writeTimestamp.toMillis() / 1000;
      console.log(timeLeft);
      setTimerDisplay(Math.floor(timeLeft));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error occured in getting Pool Time", error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      getPoolTime();
    }, 1100);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: Have a look at this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69741736/why-setinterval-inside-useeffect-hook-in-react-keeps-running) thread.